# AudioClip load issue with AssetBundles

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, assetbundle

I am trying to load an audio clip using AssetBundles but strange result.

**Actual audio file:**

[image]

**File loaded from AssetBundle:**

[image]

AudioClip gets loaded successfully but when I try to play, I get **"FMOD::Sound instance for clip "fileName" (FMOD error: File not found.)"**

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: I would check that the gameobject/file is loaded properly with the [loadFromFile](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html) command, and check that the file is actually in the bundle [manifest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundleManifest.html)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Thank you for your reply. Yes, the asset gets loaded successfully with "LoadFromFile" function. Also, that file is present in the manifest bundle.